# Automatically create help video using the live websites

Tags: video, html, user-interface

So for a tiny bit of background.  We currently have a online software product that has recently been configured for multiple branding, for example: if you visit URL 'X' you get branding of company X,  if you visit URL 'Y' you get the branding for company Y.  As part of this product, we provide online sixteen help videos that will then provide some explanation of the features of the site.  At the moment, we've used screen capture software with a voice-over to achieve relatively professional videos that we can upload and reference from YouTube.

Of course, the more brands we add, we'll then need create another sixteen videos using the appropriate branding for that Url and Company selected.  Reusing the audio is no problem but the screen capture approach feels extremely inefficient and I was wondering whether there was...

- A screen capture application that could **automate interaction** / clicks
  on a website then output as a video.  A bonus would be adding the
  pre-recorded video but this can always be inserted afterwards.
- Or a web component that would act as an **Interactive Help Element** capable of
  zooming into and out of elements as well as including audio at
  appropriate keyframes.  Moving the mouse-pointer would be a bonus but
  this would likely be restricted through JS.

Any suggestions gratefully received.